# Sorting negative integer strings in python

Tags: python, sorting

```
def sort_int_string(this_string):
    split_str = this_string.split()
    split_str.sort()
    join_str = ' '.join(split_str)
    return join_str

>>>print(sort_int_string("4 1 -1 -3"))
-1 -3 1 4
```

This code is meant to produce the proper order of "-3 -1" but for some reason I am getting this output where positive numbers are correct but the negatives are not. Any insight on what I am doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: That code won't generate that output.  Please always copy and paste transcripts exactly, rather than write what you guess it should do.

Comment: @DSM -- I'm always amazed at how quickly you pick up on small nuances like OP forgot to bind the return value of `sorted`.  You're a machine sir!

Comment: Lexicographic order is not the same as integer order.

Comment: @DSM -- Sorry. Im new to this stackoverflow thing! I repasted it exactly how I have it but I changed the sorted() to list.sort(). It still does not do what I want though. Any clue why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are sorting *strings*, not numbers, and those are sorted [*lexicographically*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order); like words in a dictionary. `-` happens to be sorted before digits, but `'1'` is still sorted before `'3'`. Furthermore, `'10'` sorts before `'2'` because `'1'` comes before `'2'` in a character table.

Sort numerically by converting each element to an integer while sorting:

```
split_str.sort(key=int)
```

Demo, with your corrected function:

```
>>> def sort_int_string(this_string):
...     split_str = this_string.split()
...     split_str.sort(key=int)
...     join_str = ' '.join(split_str)
...     return join_str
... 
>>> print(sort_int_string("4 1 -1 -3"))
-3 -1 1 4
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex:

```
>>> import re
>>> sorted(re.findall(r'-?\d+', "4 1 -1 -3"), key=int)
['-3', '-1', '1', '4']
```

That produces the strings in sorted order by their value.

You can rejoin into a string:

```
>>> sor=sorted(re.findall(r'-?\d+', "4 1 -1 -3"), key=int)
>>> ' '.join(sor)
'-3 -1 1 4'
```